# Is it possible to create "Charts" using visual Studio 2013 for Windows 8 app for Store?!

Tags: charts, windows-8.1, visual-studio-2013

I am wondering if it is possible to include a chart, say "Pie chart", in my Windows 8 App for store and it should be displayed based on the values from SQL server Database table say "Number of employees in each department". If any changes are made to the data in SQL, they should also reflect the data displayed in this chart of my app. I am using VS2013 express for Windows, SQL server 2012 to develop this.

If anyone can come up with a solution, it would be of great help.

Also, I would like to thank all those who helped me resolve previous issue. Thank you so much for your time in Advance.

-Bhargav Krishna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[How to access data from SQL Server database in Windows Store app - MSDN Sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-access-data-from-5f2602ec)

[Getting started with free Metro (Modern UI) charts for Windows 8](http://igrali.com/2013/05/25/getting-started-with-free-metro-modern-ui-charts-windows-8/)

[NuGet Package - Modern UI (Metro) Charts for Windows 8](https://nuget.org/packages/ModernChart)

Comment: Hey friend..Thanks for the links. They have provided sufficient information for me to get the job done. I really appreciate your time :)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments :)

Answer (score 0):

For the SQL matter I cannot help, but the Pie chart check if this helps.

1) Code your own; here is an article about coding your own charts:
[Pie Chart for Windows 8](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/metroapps/archive/2012/07/24/building-pie-chart-for-windows-8-metro.aspx)

2) Use plugins:
[Modern UI (Metro) Charts](http://modernuicharts.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Hey friend..Thanks for the quick response. The material you have provided to me gave sufficient information for me to get the job done. I really appreciate your time and help :)